# Duplicate symbol Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone

ld: duplicate symbol _teapot_vertices in /Users/iphone/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ImageTargets-cbbgriyhgpamtidfvkqsbglovpup/Build/Intermediates/ImageTargets.build/Debug-iphoneos/ImageTargets.build/Objects-normal/armv6/CC3ModelSampleFactory.o and /Users/iphone/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ImageTargets-cbbgriyhgpamtidfvkqsbglovpup/Build/Intermediates/ImageTargets.build/Debug-iphoneos/ImageTargets.build/Objects-normal/armv6/SYN_AR_EAGLView.o for architecture armv6
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Comment: could you please provide a bit more of verbosity in your question? in example what are you working at, and when does this happen. stuff like that

Comment: @holographix : i am merging cocos3d with Qualcomm SDK for AR project but i am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you have duplicate symbols for symbol _teapot_vertices, you are probably compiling source files which are already compiled in a static lib which you are linking to or linking to two libraries, both of which have these symbols.